# Invoice2data How to use multiline

Tags: regex

I was trying to implement Invoice2data, but I'm unable to make the multiline option work.
My pdf item section looks like this (the  is what appear in the invoice2data --debug):

```
 Term                   Product                                        Amount

 1 mo                   Basic Websites Renewal     C$99.99
                           fa6.4bc.myinfo.com
 1 mo                   Renewal Usage                                  C$0.00
                        Total
```

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data/blob/master/TUTORIAL.rst), I think the yml should look like something like this:

```
lines:
    start: Term\s+Product\s+Amount
    end: \s+Total
    first_line: \d+\smo
    #last_line: .+
    line: (?P<term>.+)\s+(?P<product>.+)\s+(?P<amount>\d+\.\d+)
```

start -> fetch the header

end -> fetch the word 'Total'

first_line -> fetch '1 mo'

last_line -> it's not mendatory, so I just removed it

line: honestly, this line confuses me. I copy/paste in from the doc and tried to run it in regexr.com and regex101.com but both of them couldn't resolve the line... I think it suppose to take the result of regex '.+' and put it in the  variable?

As you can see, the second line doesn't always appear. It would be nice to keep it, but any answer would help.

When I execute the command, this is what I get:

```
DEBUG:invoice2data.extract.invoice_template:field=lines | regexp=OrderedDict([('start', 'Term\\s+Product\\s+Amount'), ('end', '\\s+Total'), ('first_line', '\\d+\\smo'), ('line', '(?P<term>.+)\\s+(?P<product>.+)\\s+(?P<amount>\\d+\\.\\d+)')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/bin/invoice2data", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoice2data/main.py", line 201, in main
    res = extract_data(f.name, templates=templates, input_module=input_module)
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoice2data/main.py", line 93, in extract_data
    return t.extract(optimized_str)
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoice2data/extract/invoice_template.py", line 174, in extract
    res_find = re.findall(v, optimized_str)
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/home/mr/PycharmProjects/pdf_to_pinv/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 237, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[cachekey]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'
```

Does anyone knows how to use the multi-line function?